# Regular Expression for Google Cloud Metrics

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, metrics

I am looking on how to create a Regular expression to get a certain value from a string

```
 hello:world#winter#new | store id:0f516-af8-489-a1-a6f1da | Successfully reviewed
```

An Expression which will extract `0f516-af8-489-a1-a6f1da` from the string.

I've tried the expression generator `\bstore id:[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\b` but its still returning the whole string instead of the specific ID.

Hope to get some assistance on this.

Regards!

Comment: You just need a group, `\bstore id:([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\b`

Comment: tried it - its still returning the whole string - any suggestions?

Comment: No, unless this part of GCP allows the use of lookarounds which I do not think is likely. `(?<=\bstore id:)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\b`

Comment: It doesn't allow - for some reason metric explorer keeps showing the whole string for this field, would you know if metric explorer is meant to show value for fields after regex is applied or is it meant to show data from field pre regex?

Comment: If you mean the metric filter, then it only filters by metric name

Comment: Ok then how can we view data to confirm if Regex is getting applied on the field or not?